# Scala trait extending abstract class, how do I know whether an abstract method has been implemented or not

Tags: scala, overriding, abstract, traits

I am new to scala, and I have the following question

```
abstract class A {
    def foo(): List[String]
}

trait AA extends A {
    override def foo(): List[String] = {
        // Something like 
        // If super.foo is implemented, "AA" +: super.foo
        // If super.foo is not implemented, List("AA")
    }
}

class B extends A with AA {
    override def foo(): List[String] = {
        // I think the trait will have the implementation, so I should only need to do:
        super.foo
    }
}
```

Basically I would like each trait to add one part to the result of foo, so that I can have the final result by mixing multiple such traits. I think I can make the foo method in class A to return empty List, but I am just curious whether there is a way to check whether the method in parent has been implemented or not.

Also, please let me know if there is an anti-pattern.

Comment: it looks like as decorator pattern but I'm not sure what your goal is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the [stackable trait pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html).

So you have an abstract class `A` which declares some method `foo()`, and you have a "decorator" of that method who says something like "I extend `A` and I would like to append 'AA' to whatever `foo()` returns".

```
abstract class A {
  def foo(): List[String]
}

trait AA extends A {
  abstract override def foo(): List[String] = "AA" :: super.foo()
}
```

Note the `abstract override`, this is the key. It allows us to append some behaviour to an abstract class.

Now let's say we do something like this:

```
class WithoutImpl extends A with AA {
  override def foo(): List[String] = {
    super.foo() // fails; needs "abstract override" or implementation
  }
}
```

This fails because everyone is decorating, but noone is actually implementing.

Let's add an implementation trait:

```
trait AAA extends A {
  override def foo(): List[String] = List("AAA")
}
```

Now we might do:

```
class WithImpl extends AA with AAA {
  def myFoo(): List[String] = {
    super.foo() // error! wrong order of initialization
  }
}
```

This will still fail due to the order of mixins. We must first provide an implementation, and then we provide the decorator(s), who will then keep adding behaviours.

```
class WithImpl extends AAA with AA  {
  def myFoo(): List[String] = {
    super.foo() // works!
  }
}

println((new WithImpl().myFoo())) // List("AA", "AAA")
```

You can add as many decorators as you wish, just pay attention to the order. E.g. if we had `BB` and `CC` similarly to `AA`, we could do:

```
class WithImpl extends AAA with AA with BB with CC  {
  def myFoo(): List[String] = {
    super.foo() // List(CC, BB, AA, AAA)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so this means I still need an implementation in the whole path at an early place. Is there a way I can do: If super is implemented, call it; if super is not implemented, do the first implementation?

Comment: You mean at compile time or at run time? If you need at runtime, then I don't know, it should involve reflection API and similar magic and I try to keep out of that. If you want to know at compile time (e.g. you are using a library whose source you don't have), then the compiler will tell you if it's not implemented (that's `WithoutImpl` in my example). Or am I misunderstanding something in your question?

Comment: Thanks, I was asking about runtime. But your solution works, and I will guarantee that there is an implementation before.

Comment: I'm new to scala and I'm trying to understand why in WithoutImpl, the function is considered to have no implementation when foo() in trait AA did define an implementation.  Am I right in assuming if "abstract" was added, it will work?